# Dropdown menu popper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu but I get this error:

```
"Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6"
```

I found some questions about it  here but none of them worked for me. How do I import this popper.js?

edit1:

I just found a way to import with script tag...it was all this time in bootstrap documentation. But, there's one more problem: The code is free of erros but my dropdown button isn't working. I tried every single dropdown in bootstrap documentation, I ctrl+c - ctrl-v all of them and none of them are working, I click on the button and nothing happens :(

```
 !doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>About us</title>


<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<link href="Sobre-Nós.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>







</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, it's just:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation: https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js#installation

There are several ways of installing popper.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm supposed to do like <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.5/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
?

Comment: Isn't working :( Even if I to like above I get the same error :(

Comment: Yes, you are right. Put that line of code before loading bootstrap so it's able to know what "Popper" is.

Comment: Be sure you include the whole url like this: "https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.5/dist/umd/popper.js". That is, including "https" protocol.

Comment: So, I wrot exactly: <script src="unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.5/dist/umd/popper.js"> </script> and the new error is: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Why don't you download it? After that, you can create a reference to your local file, something like this: src="popper.js"

Comment: I just found a way to import with <script>...it was all this time in bootstrap documentation. But, there's one more problem: The code is free of erros but my dropdown button isn't working. I tried every single dropdown in bootstrap documentation, I ctrl+c - ctrl-v all of them and none of them are working, I click on the button and nothing happens :(

Comment: You have to initialize those components before using them. Are you initializing them? The code to initialize them is also in the documentation.